# Generate popup message which shows the coordinates on drawn and edited polygon in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am using Leaflet map. I am trying to have a popup message which shows the coordinates on drawn polygon. However when I am trying to edit the drawn polygon using the edit layer the coordinates in the popup is not updating it will still read the initial drawing:

```js
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (e) => {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  if (type === 'rectangle' || type === 'polygon') {
    var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs()[0];
    var coordinates = latlngs.map(coord => [coord.lng, coord.lat]);

    var popupContent = '<p>Coordinates:</p><pre>' + JSON.stringify(coordinates, null, 2) + '</pre>';
    var popup = layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    console.log("Created Event - Initial Coordinates:", popupContent);

    layer.on('editable:vertex:drag', (e) => {
      var editedLayer = e.layer;
      var editedCoordinates = editedLayer.getLatLngs()[0].map(coord => [coord.lng, coord.lat]);
      var updatedPopupContent = '<p>Coordinates:</p><pre>' + JSON.stringify(editedCoordinates, null, 2) + '</pre>';
      popup.setContent(updatedPopupContent);
      console.log("Editable Vertex Drag Event - Updated Coordinates:", updatedPopupContent);
    });
  }

  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `Leaflet.draw` plugin and so also not with the `editable:vertex:drag` event. Instead of it I used `edit` event and that worked.

Here is the code that worked:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (e) => {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  if (type === 'rectangle' || type === 'polygon') {
    var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs()[0];
    var coordinates = latlngs.map(coord => [coord.lng, coord.lat]);

    var popupContent = '<p>Coordinates:</p><pre>' + JSON.stringify(coordinates, null, 2) + '</pre>';
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);

    layer.on('edit', (e) => {
      var editedLayer = e.target;
      var editedCoordinates = editedLayer.getLatLngs()[0].map(coord => [coord.lng, coord.lat]);
      var updatedPopupContent = '<p>Coordinates:</p><pre>' + JSON.stringify(editedCoordinates, null, 2) + '</pre>';
      editedLayer.getPopup().setContent(updatedPopupContent);
    });
  }

  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
```